# Hide only 200 or 2xx XHR calls on Cypress test runner

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress v12.17.4. I would like to hide all successful XHR calls but keep the unsuccessful ones, like 400, 401...

I've added this to my cypress.config.ts file

```
e2e: {
    hideXHRInCommandLog: true,
}
```

and this to e2e.js file

```
// Hide fetch/XHR requests from command log
if (Cypress.config('hideXHRInCommandLog')) {
  const app = window.top;

  if (app && !app.document.head.querySelector('[data-hide-command-log-request]')) {
    const style = app.document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '.command-name-request, .command-name-xhr { display: none }';
    style.setAttribute('data-hide-command-log-request', '');

    app.document.head.appendChild(style);
  }
}
```

I guess this excludes all XHR calls to be displayed in the Cypress test runner. What and where should I configure to exclude only 2xx XHR calls?